# Как выровнять содержимое flex-элемента по правому краю?

Tags: css, flexbox, выравнивание

Внутри flex-контейнера есть 2 flex-элемента:

- 1 слева
- 2 справа (margin-left: auto;)

Если внутри flex-элементов мало текста (1 строка), то все выглядит хорошо.
Но если текста много, и flex-элементам приходится переносить текст на новую строку, то они начинают заполнять собой все пространство - и в правом элементе появляется отступ справа.

Надо, чтобы текст внутри правого flex-элемента заканчивался там же, где flex-контейнер.

- Либо выровнять flex-элемент по ширине его содержимого
- Либо выровнять подблок с текстом по правому краю flex-элемента

Не получается ни то, ни то - подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать?

```css
/* CSS styles */
.header{
  display: flex;
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
}

.left{
  background-color: grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.right{
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.right-text{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="left">Левый блок</div>
  <div class="right">Правый блок.....</div>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="left">Левый.................... блок..........................................</div>
  <div class="right">Правый блок.....</div>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="left">Левый.................... блок..........................................</div>
  <div class="right"><div class="right-text">Правый блок.....</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавь правому блоку `flex: 0 0 auto`

Comment: Второй нолик поставит flex-shrink: 0 - и это запретит элементу уменьшаться - тогда да, отступов не будет, спасибо!

А есть ли возможность выровнять содержимое элемента по правому краю, оставив ему возможность уменьшаться?

Comment: `text-aling: right`

Comment: Да, это свойство работает - но оно выравнивает текст по правому краю.
А хотелось выровнять по правому краю именно содержимое элемента - т.е. блок (в данном случае, с текстом)

Comment: `justify-content: flex-end` для `.header` будет выравнивать блоки по правому краю.